# Get node count from XML File based on child node value

Tags: xml, xml-deserialization, uipath

I am reading XML file in UIPATH and my requirement is to count the number of entries for brand “BMW” despite its model. GIven example, should return “3”. Could you please help me to achieve this or give leads to find a solution.

```
<country>
        <state>Texas</state>
            <cars>        
                         <brand>BMW</brand>
                         <model>X1</model>
                         <unit>210000</unit>        
            </cars>
            <cars>        
                        <brand>BMW</brand>
                        <model>X6</model>
                        <unit>210000</unit>     
            </cars>
            <cars>        
                        <brand>BMW</brand>
                        <model>X7</model>
                         <unit>210000</unit>        
            </cars>
            <cars>        
                         <brand>Ford</brand>
                         <model>mustang</model>
                         <unit>319000</unit>        
            </cars>
            <cars>        
                         <brand>Volvo</brand>
                        <model>XC90</model>
                         <unit>91100</unit>     
            </cars> 
    </country>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Execute XPath](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/execute-xpath) function and use the following XPath to get the count in one action only:

```
count(//cars/brand[text()='BMW'])
```

Comment: Marek, Thanks! it worked. Now, the real issue is to dump data into excel.. I've multiple XML files and only few files have more than 1 same brand entry. So I've just   extracted brand, model, unit using EXECUTE XPATH but how to loop this through in order to put 3 records in excel.

Brand  --- Model ---  Unit
BMW   --- X1 --- 2100000
BMW   --- X6 --- 2100000
BMW   --- X7 --- 2100000

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach to go through the xml (you can convert it to json before to make it easier) and once done you put an if condition to know if it is BMW that adds count++

That occurs to me.